# Inserting CLOB data with ANT

Tags: database, ant, clob

I am trying to use Ant to initialize my Oracle database by using Ant. I followed this guide:

http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/ant/AntScripttoInsertDatainMysqlTable.shtml

and that works but I was wondering if anyone knows how to insert CLOB data into Oracle tables using Ant.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in this [Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:388196216305) article, it should be possible to just insert `VARCHAR2`-values like that:

```
create table t ( x clob );

insert into t values ( 'MY CLOB CONTENT' );
```

**EDIT**
If you want to insert from a file, it should be possible to use the [loadfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html) task to get the file into a property, replace the newlines somehow and use that property in the insert.

Comment: Kind of, I was hoping to be able to specify the xml file that I wanted to be stored as a CLOB.